# Where do custom Solr schemas go in Riak?

Tags: schema, ubuntu, riak, solr

I have checked these two pages in the Riak docs 
http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.0/developing/usage/search/ 
http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.0/developing/usage/search-schemas/ 

and they tell how to make a custom schema and how to attach it to an index, but they seem to expect the schema to be in a certain folder to do so. Whenever I try adding the schema through curl like this:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:8098/search/schema/users \
    -H 'Content-Type:application/xml' \
    --data-binary @user_schema.xml
```

it throws an error saying it isn't found. I've tried inserting the path too. I've found solutions online saying that it's somewhere in the data folder, but those were back in 2015 and I'm using version 2.2 of Riak now. Has anyone else recently had success with adding a custom solr schema to Riak?

PS - I'm using ubuntu/trusty64 in a vm